# Parsing through webpages after logging in and extracting data from table

Tags: python, excel, pandas, selenium, web-crawler

I've made a simple web parser using selenium to mine stock levels from a supplier website.

Currently, it's function is to log in to the website, click to the orders page on the site after login, input a barcode to show a list of products (no more than 50), and then extract data from each table row, being barcode, product name, and stock level. Currently, every product that's listed has a different ID, which I intend to circumvent through working through a list of ids I've made (numbering 50, as that's the most individual products shown in the table on the website). The barcodes in question are searched from an excel spreadsheet and individually searched in the barcode searcher, this is a sample of the code I'm currently working with.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

variables, fill in with stuff
usernameStr = 'putYourUsernameHere'
passwordStr = 'putYourPasswordHere'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('website'))
pointer = 0

#opens workbook with barcodes and makes a list of them, fill in with stuff
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsm', sheetname=0) # can also index sheet by name or fetch all sheets
Barcodes = df['column name'].tolist()
length = len(Barcodes)

# fill in username and password and sign in
username = browser.find_element_by_id('UserName')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)
password = browser.find_element_by_id('Password')
password.send_keys(passwordStr)
signInButton = browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_cplMain_Login2_LoginButton')
signInButton.click()

#go to barcode page, fill in with ids
navigateToOrdering = browser.find_element_by_id('')
navigateToOrdering.click()
stocksearcher = browser.find_element_by_id('')
stocksearcherbutton = browser.find_element_by_id('')

site_stock = browser.find_element_by_id('')
site_barcode = browser.find_element_by_id('')
site_name = browser.find_element_by_id('')
list_to_pass = ['product1value' - 'product2value']
listRange = len(list_to_pass)
for range in length:
    stocksearcher.send_keys(Barcodes[pointer])
    stocksearcherbutton.click()
    pointer =+1
        for range in listRange:
        stock = site_stock.get_attribute('title')
        barcode = site_barcode.get_attribute('title')
        name = site_name.get_attribute('title')
```

Comment: what is the issue here?

Comment: At the moment, I don't know if the for loop or the nested for loop will work, also how to ensure that it doesn't run into an error if an empty value is met

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Beautiful Soup 4, it's a library that makes it easy to scrape information from web pages. You find all docs [here](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)!

to install it use the command:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: Beautiful soup doesn't quite work with a responsive website layout, as it parses through static websites and downloads information that way, or so I've gathered.